# Supplement local data for geocoder using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am running a map of the location of a few facilities with their name and coordinate data. I want the geocoder to be able to search for the name of the facility.

Mapbox has a great example of this, but their example shows a use case where the dataset is loaded INTO the actual code. My dataset is much larger and it is currently located on a .geojson file in the project folder.

How can I transform this code to work for my example?

I tried to call back my dataset into the geocoder code by using

```
  var myData =getSource('BRdata');
```

then calling

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myData.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = myData.features[I];

// handle queries with different capitalization than the source data by calling toLowerCase()
     if (feature.properties.HandlerId.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {

     feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.HandlerId;
     feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
      matchingFeatures.push(feature);
 }
}
  return matchingFeatures;
}
```

to get the data into the geocoder, but its not working. I get the error  "

> myData is not defined

A working plunker can be seen here
https://plnkr.co/edit/UUaf6OCgvoavwshdUdN9?p=preview

> Expected result: Geocoder to call .geojson data into the search field
>   Actual result: Geocoder cannot find the .geojson.
>
> Error: "myData is not defined"

edit added this code which includes the new var myData:

```
    function forwardGeocoder(query) {
  // Fetch data on server and serve me the raw geojson
  var myData = fetch('test-plnkr.json').then(res => res.json());
    var matchingFeatures = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = myData.features[i];
    // handle queries with different capitalization than the source data by calling toLowerCase()
    if (feature.properties.HandlerId.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    // add a tree emoji as a prefix for custom data results
    // using carmen geojson format: https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/blob/master/carmen-geojson.md
    feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.HandlerId;
    feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    //feature['place_type'] = ['park'];
    matchingFeatures.push(feature);
    }
    }
    return matchingFeatures;
    }

map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
localGeocoder: forwardGeocoder,
zoom: 14,
placeholder: "Enter search e.g. Lincoln Park",
mapboxgl: mapboxgl
}));
```

**FIX:**

copy and paste your geojson inside of:

```
var customData = { *your geojson data* }
```

then load the geocoder using the below code

```
function forwardGeocoder(query) {
var matchingFeatures = [];
for (var i = 0; i < customData.features.length; i++) {
var feature = customData.features[i];
// handle queries with different capitalization than the source data by      calling toLowerCase()
if     (feature.properties.yourPropertyId.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase())   !== -1) {
// add a tree emoji as a prefix for custom data results

feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.yourPropertyId;
feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
//feature['place_type'] = ['park'];
matchingFeatures.push(feature);
}
}
return matchingFeatures;
}

map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
localGeocoder: forwardGeocoder,
zoom: 13,
placeholder: "search for building here",
mapboxgl: mapboxgl
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: `getSource` is not a function and you need to re-request your data.

`getSource` is not a function in your plunkr code, so I think you meant to write `map.getSource`. Even still, `map.getSource` isn't going to give you the raw GeoJSON data back. Check out this [issue on Github in the mapbox-gl-js repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1762).

The suggestion by Vladimir is to request the data by doing a `fetch` for it, which would look something like this:

```
// Fetch data on server and serve me the raw geojson
var myData = fetch('data.json').then(res => res.json());
```

Comment: thanks, so I updated the code here but when I type "abc1" (the name of one of the facilities under "HandlerId" it still doesn't load. updated the code in the main post above

Comment: the error is "TypeError: myData.features is undefined[Learn More]"

Comment: I changed moving the variable out of the code and placed it at the very top, but im still getting the same error. for some reason myData.features is not being recognized. any ideas?

Comment: figured it out. ended up reloading the geojson as its own variable and calling that by the geocoder.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed these @DeebaYavrom! Glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom how did you reload the geojson. I am having this same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @blg2 yeah so you just need to copy and paste the geojson in a new variable, then call it back using the geocoder code. i made an edit in the original posting that explains whats going on. i dont think its ideal since it has to load the same dataset twice, but this is the easiest way i could make it work

Comment: @DeebaYavrom thanks, I thought thats what you meant. I wish there was a better way like it could just search my tileset.