# How to add external data for Geocoder in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am running a map of the location of a few facilities with their name and coordinate data. I want the geocoder to be able to search for the name of the facility.

Mapbox has a great example of this, but their example shows a use case where the dataset is loaded INTO the actual code. My dataset is much larger and it is currently located on a .geojson file in the project folder.

How can I transform this code to work for my example?

I tried to call back my dataset into the geocoder code by using

```
  var myData =getSource('BRdata');
```

then calling

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myData.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = myData.features[I];

// handle queries with different capitalization than the source data by calling toLowerCase()
     if (feature.properties.HandlerId.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {

     feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.HandlerId;
     feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
      matchingFeatures.push(feature);
 }
}
  return matchingFeatures;
}
```

to get the data into the geocoder, but its not working. I get the error  "

> myData is not defined

A working plunker can be seen here
https://plnkr.co/edit/UUaf6OCgvoavwshdUdN9?p=preview

> Expected result: Geocoder to call .geojson data into the search field
>   Actual result: Geocoder cannot find the .geojson.
>
> Error: "myData is not defined"

edit added this code which includes the new var myData:

```
    function forwardGeocoder(query) {
  // Fetch data on server and serve me the raw geojson
  var myData = fetch('test-plnkr.json').then(res => res.json());
    var matchingFeatures = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = myData.features[i];
    // handle queries with different capitalization than the source data by calling toLowerCase()
    if (feature.properties.HandlerId.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    // add a tree emoji as a prefix for custom data results
    // using carmen geojson format: https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/blob/master/carmen-geojson.md
    feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.HandlerId;
    feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    //feature['place_type'] = ['park'];
    matchingFeatures.push(feature);
    }
    }
    return matchingFeatures;
    }

map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
localGeocoder: forwardGeocoder,
zoom: 14,
placeholder: "Enter search e.g. Lincoln Park",
mapboxgl: mapboxgl
}));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supplement local data for geocoder using Mapbox GL JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294040/supplement-local-data-for-geocoder-using-mapbox-gl-js)

Comment: You seem to have posted this question twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294040/supplement-local-data-for-geocoder-using-mapbox-gl-js?rq=1